# nginx passenger is showing 404 not found error for every urls in my rails app in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, http-status-code-404, passenger

I am preparing my development environment with nginx and passenger but seems like only root of the app is loading the home page every other url are showing a nginx 404 not found error. but the app works perfect with webrick.I am running on ubuntu 16.04.

```
    # Here is the routes.rb file of the app



    Pinteresting::Application.routes.draw do
    root 'pins#index'
       resources :pins

      devise_for :users
      # root "pages#home"

      get 'about' => 'pages#about'

    end
```

root path is working anyway with nignx but because of assets not loading home page seems like cluttered

```
    # AND THE NGINX CONF FILE
```

```
       gzip on;
       gzip_disable "msie6";  

        include /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;




# NGINX DEFAULT FILE[enter image description here][1]
# passenger configuration
    server {
```

passenger configuration are done using the doc, and has specified app environment, app path etc..
          server_name localhost;
          passenger_enabled on;
          passenger_app_env development;
          root /home/aju/pinteresting/public;

```
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/8eNUA => nginx.conf file                          http://imgur.com/a/h3p8d => nginx/default file

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this :(